# $.get() vs $.post() response ( object response, string response) Gson on servlet

Tags: java, jquery, json, ajax, gson

```
JsonObject responseJson = new JsonObject();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
responseJson.addProperty("titles",gson.toJson(processWSResponseList));

respWriter.print(responseJson.toString());
```

**Above code is in a GET servlet, POST servlet
GET servlet response in javascript developertools is "typeof response" is "object"**

POST servlet response in javascript developertools is "typeof response" is "string"

**why typeof is different with the same code ? String , Object**

$.get(url);
$.post(url,data);

Thanks,
Sri

Comment: Maybe $.post doesn't automatically parse the json when you don't set dataType to json but $.get does.

Comment: It seems better I use $.ajax () with parameters rather than $.post

Comment: $.post(finalURL, body, "json"); return result as "string" only. using $.ajax() seems to be working mehtod: POST, dataType:json